# Passing data in prepareForSegue (Swift 2)

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to navigate to a viewcontroller (JobDetailsVC) when a user clicks on a row in a tableview. I am a bit confused with doing things in Swift 2 and currently I am getting an error 'Cannot assign a value of type 'JobDetailsTableVC.datastruct' to type 'JobDetails?'.

Here is the code in my prepareforsegue

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

       let JobDetailsViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! JobDetailsVC

         if let selectedJobCell = sender as? JobDetailsCell {
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(selectedJobCell)!
            let selectedJob = TableData[indexPath.row]

            print(selectedJob)
            JobDetailsViewController.Job = selectedJob
        }
    }
```

selectedJob is being correctly assigned the data that I want to pass eg;

*datastruct(date: Optional("12 Mar 2016"), reference: Optional("this is a reference"), start: Optional("11:38am"), end: Optional("6:40pm"), description: Optional("this is a description"), duration: Optional("7:10"), job_id: Optional("348"), token: Optional("11dc886610"), notes: nil)
[]*

The datastruct comes from

```
    struct datastruct
{
    var date:String?
    var reference:String?
    var start:String?
    var end:String?
    var description:String?
    var duration:String?
    var job_id:String?
    var token:String?
    var notes:String?



    init(add: NSDictionary)
    {
        date = add["date"] as? String
        reference = add["reference"] as? String
        start = add["start"] as? String
        end = add["end"] as? String
        description = add["description"] as? String
        job_id = add["job_id"] as? String
        token = add["token"] as? String
        duration = add["duration"] as? String
        notes = add["notes"] as? String
    }
}
```

In the current view controller I have this:

```
var Job = [JobDetails]()
```

In the view controller I want to send the data to (JobDetailsVC) I have this:

```
var Job: JobDetails?
```

I have JobDetails declared in a class

```
class JobDetails {

var date:String?
var reference:String?
var start:String?
var end:String?
var description:String?
var duration:String?
var job_id:String?
var token:String?
var notes:String?

init(date: String, reference: String, start: String, end: String, description: String, duration: String, job_id: String, token: String, notes: String)
{

    self.date = date
    self.reference = reference
    self.start=start
    self.end=end
    self.description=description
    self.job_id=job_id
    self.token=token
    self.notes=notes
    self.duration=duration

}
```

}

Can anyone please help me ? Thanks

Comment: As the error says you are trying to assign a datastruct to a variable of type JobDetails here: `JobDetailsViewController.Job = selectedJob`. If datastruct and JobDetails have the same properties why have both?

Comment: Not an answer, but your variable names should start with a lowercase, i.e. `let JobDetailsViewController` -> `jobDetailsViewController`. It will make it a lot easier to know when you are talking about a class and when about an object. If I read `JobDetailsViewController.Job` I would assume you are referring to a `Job` enum/struct inside a class called `JobDetailsViewController`

Comment: Thanks @beyowulf, you are right and this helped me fix the problem. There was no need to declare a class JobDetails.

Answer (score -1):

Notice that you're defining Job as an Array of JobDetails:

```
var Job = [JobDetails]()
```

Once selectedJob is just one item, you cannot do this:

```
JobDetailsViewController.Job = selectedJob
```

Just change the definition of Job to:

```
var Job = JobDetails()
```

But if you want to keep Job as an Array of Jobs on your VC, just do this:

```
JobDetailsViewController.Job += [selectedJob]
```